# Why the WM_VSCROLL message is implemented twice when clicking once to get the spin control value?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get a spin control value through the `WM_VSCROLL` message, but there is something unusual happening, the code implements twice on clicking on the spin control once.

```
case WM_VSCROLL:
{
    switch (GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam)) {
    case JOB_SPIN:
    {
        UINT spin_pos = SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, JOB_SPIN, UDM_GETPOS32, 0, 0);
        OutputDebugString(Mem->ToString(spin_pos).c_str()); // Mem->ToString, to convert a number to a string
    }

    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

When trying to examine the `WParam` value of each message I find there is a difference:

[image]

**What's wrong with my code or there is something missing?**

Comment: Your fragment is too small to find the issue. Taking into account your style not to put break operator in case statements (like in case JOB_SPIN) is could be that the control flow comes from the previous case statement in switch operator. Show more surrounding code.

Comment: Did you try looking at the `wParam` of each scroll message to see if they are different values?

Comment: @DamirTenishev: There is no other important code, that code is the only one responsible for handling the value of the spin control.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, the values are different in each scroll message. Please look at the new update.

Comment: @LionKing did you try [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are simply not looking at the message's `wParam` to determine *why* each message is being sent to you.

Per the [`WM_VSCROLL` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll):

> wParam
>
> The HIWORD specifies the current position of the scroll box if the LOWORD is SB_THUMBPOSITION or SB_THUMBTRACK; otherwise, this word is not used.
>
> The LOWORD specifies a scroll bar value that indicates the user's scrolling request. This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> | Value | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | SB_BOTTOM | Scrolls to the lower right. |
> | SB_ENDSCROLL | Ends scroll. |
> | SB_LINEDOWN | Scrolls one line down. |
> | SB_LINEUP | Scrolls one line up. |
> | SB_PAGEDOWN | Scrolls one page down. |
> | SB_PAGEUP | Scrolls one page up. |
> | SB_THUMBPOSITION | The user has dragged the scroll box (thumb) and released the mouse button. The HIWORD indicates the position of the scroll box at the end of the drag operation. |
> | SB_THUMBTRACK | The user is dragging the scroll box. This message is sent repeatedly until the user releases the mouse button. The HIWORD indicates the position that the scroll box has been dragged to. |
> | SB_TOP | Scrolls to the upper left. |

So, in your case:

- In the 1st message, where the `wParam` is `196612` (`0x30004`), `LOWORD(wParam)` is `4` (`SB_THUMBPOSITION`), meaning the user has scrolled the scrollbar. `HIWORD(wParam)` contains the new scroll position `3`.
- In the 2nd message, where the `wParam` is `196616` (`0x30008`), `LOWORD(wParam)` is `8` (`SB_ENDSCROLL`), meaning the user has finished scrolling. Ignore what is in `HIWORD(wParam)`.

Simply update your `switch` to take `wParam` into account, eg:

```
case WM_VSCROLL:
{
    HWND hwndScrollBar = (HWND)lParam;
    switch (GetDlgCtrlID(hwndScrollBar))
    {
        case JOB_SPIN:
        {
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == SB_THUMBPOSITION)
            {
                //UINT spin_pos = HIWORD(wParam);
                UINT spin_pos = SendMessage(hwndScrollBar, UDM_GETPOS32, 0, 0);
                OutputDebugString(Mem->ToString(spin_pos).c_str());
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: That point was not clear and I did not understand it when I read the documentation.
it is just to tell you the status of clicking on the spin control. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I found that I can use `HIWORD(wParam)` instead of `SendMessage` to get the spin value (position).

Comment: @LionKing that depends on the values used in your spin control. Do pay attention to the fact that `HIWORD(wParam)` is a 16-bit unsigned integer, so it is limited to values in the range `0..65535`, whereas `UDM_GETPOS32` returns a 32-bit unsigned integer instead, which has a much larger range of values, `0..4294967295`

Comment: Right, but in my case, a 16-bit unsigned integer Is enough (from 1 to 6) is just what I want.